# Why does Python2 to Python3 converter put "items()" into "list"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, items

I use a tool to reformat my code from Python2 to Python3. One of the things that it always does is replacing

```
my_dict.items()
```

by

```
list(my_dict.items())
```

What is the motivation behind that? I assume that `items()` do not guaranty the ordering (it is stochastic, since dictionary is not ordered). So, by using `list` we order the `key, value` pairs.

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `keys()`, `values()`, and `items()` methods of `list` in 3.x return views rather than lists, so to preserve their 2.x behavior we need to convert the view into a list.

If this old behavior is not required (e.g. we only ever iterate over the result) then the call to `list()` can be removed.